# Word order for personnal pronouns in questions and after prepositions

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, ordre-des-mots, interrogative, pronoms-personnels

I'm confused about transforming these two sentences using *les pronoms personnels* :

> As-tu donné les clés à ta voisine ?

correct transformation:

> Les lui as-tu données ?

why is

> As-tu les lui données ?

wrong ?

---

> La danseuse distribue ses photos pour ses admirateurs.
>
> Elle les distribue pour eux.

being correct, but what's wrong with

> Elle les eux distribue.

Only when the verb goes with the preposition "à" (le complément d'objet direct), the pronom is put before the verb and "à" vanishes, but in case of other prepositions (le complément d'objet indirect) the preposition is kept the pronom is not put between COD and verb? Are there cases when a COI stands in between COD and verb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.**
La première question concerne la place des pronoms personnels compléments dans la phrase. La règle générale est de mettre les pronoms personnels compléments avant le verbe, et c'est vrai aussi dans les phrases interrogatives<sup>1</sup> :

> Les lui as-tu données ?
>   Est-ce que tu les lui as données ?

**2.**
La deuxième question concerne l'utilisation des pronoms personnels quand le complément du verbe est introduit par une préposition.

Après certaines prépositions (*pour, avec, devant, chez*, etc.) on est obligé de garder la préposition, ce qui entraîne l'emploi du pronom personnel qu'on appelle « tonique », qui est distinct du pronom personnel COI. Et le couple [préposition + pronom tonique] se place après le verbe.

Comparer *distribuer pour* :

> Les supporters distribuent les photos pour les footballeurs.
>   Les supporters les distribuent pour eux.

Et *distribuer à* :

> La danseuse distribue ses photos à ses admirateurs.
>   La danseuse les leur distribue.

*Parler à* :

> Je parlerai au chef.
>   Je lui parlerai.

*Parler avec* :

> Je parlerai avec le chef.
>   Je parlerai avec lui.

Certains verbes nécessitant l'emploi de la préposition *à* oblige aussi au maintient de la préposition quand on remplace le complément par un pronom personnel, et donc on emploie le pronom tonique, et le couple [à + pronom tonique] se place après le verbe :

*Penser à* quand le complément est une personne :

> Je pense à mes parents.
>   Je pense à eux.
>   J'y pense.

Par contre :

> Je pense à mes vacances.
>   J'y pense.

On n'emploierait pas le pronom tonique pour remplacer une chose dans ce cas.

---

As a general rule object personnel pronouns come before the verb, direct object coming before indirect object. Questions follow that rule, but not orders.

Your second question is whether we have to keep the preposition that introduces the object when it is replaced by a pronoun.
Some verbs require to keep the preposition that introduces the object when the noun is replaced by a pronoun. In that case we have to use the [tonic pronoun](http://www.elearningfrench.com/french-course-2-lesson-1-grammar-2.html) ; and preposition + pronoun are placed together unseparated after the verb.

<sup>1. Les règles sont différentes à l'impératif.</sup>